# How to handle NumberFormatException with Java StreamAPI

Tags: java, exception, java-stream, numberformatexception

Is there a way to filter out all values that are bigger than the max value that can be stored in a `Long` using Stream API?

The current situation is that you can search in the frontend with a simple search bar after some customers by using their ID.

For example: `123456789, 10987654321.` If you put a *"separator"* between these two IDs, everything works. But if you forget the *"separator"* my code is trying to parse `12345678910987654321` into a Long and I guess there is the problem.

That causes a `NumberFormatException` after trying to search. Is there a way to filter these numbers out that can't be parsed into a `Long` because they are too big?

```
String hyphen = "-";

String[] customerIds = bulkCustomerIdProperty.getValue()
              .replaceAll("[^0-9]", hyphen)
              .split(hyphen);
...
customerFilter.setCustomerIds(Arrays.asList(customerIds).stream()
              .filter(n -> !n.isEmpty()) 
              .map(n -> Long.valueOf(n)) // convert to Long
              .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: If you forget a separator between two numbers, you surely want a feedback about the fact that you did something fundamentally wrong, rather than filtering the values and silently getting a completely wrong result (which looks plausible *in the worst case*) due to skipping two numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either extract parsing into a separate method and wrap it with a `try/catch`, or use `BigInteger` to eliminate values that exceed the range of `long`.

Example with `BigInteger`:

```
Set<Long> result =  Stream.of("", "12345", "9999999999999999999999999999")
        .filter(n -> !n.isEmpty())
        .map(BigInteger::new)
        .filter(n -> n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)) <= 0 &&
                     n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE)) >= 0)
        .map(BigInteger::longValueExact) // convert to Long
        .peek(System.out::println) // printing the output
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Example with handling `NumberFormatException` in a separate method:

```
Set<Long> result =  Stream.of("", "12345", "9999999999999999999999999999")
        .filter(n -> !n.isEmpty())
        .map(n -> safeParse(n))
        .filter(OptionalLong::isPresent)
        .map(OptionalLong::getAsLong) // extracting long primitive and boxing it into Long
        .peek(System.out::println) // printing the output
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

public static OptionalLong safeParse(String candidate) {
    try {
        return OptionalLong.of(Long.parseLong(candidate));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return OptionalLong.empty();
    }
}
```

**Output** (from `peek()`)

```
12345
```

Comment: Doesn’t Java have a built-in try-parse method that doesn’t throw an exception on failure?

Comment: @Dai No, contrary to JavaScript and some other languages in which you'll get `NaN` while attempting to parse an invalid string, in Java the result will be a runtime exception. Take a looks at the declarations of methods [`valueOf` and `parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#method-summary), they all declare to throw (*and will throw*)  `NumberFormatException`. That is done in order to emphasize that something is wrong with the logic (*in your application, in the API you are using, etc.*), because you are not receiving the expected data.

Comment: That’s surprising considering that runtime exceptions aren’t cheap. I was thinking there’d be a method that returns a boxed `Integer` on success or `null` on failure - or an `int` parser that returns `long` values (to encompass the set of valid `int` values and error codes). Still no hope for `out` or `ref` params in Java then?

Comment: @Dai You might want to explore the reason of this behavior to prevent malfunctioning instead of hiding it somehow. Normally, runtime exceptions must not be handled with a catch block.

Comment: None of the alternative API designs I suggested would “hide” malfunctioning. Parsing methods can still throw exceptions for _exceptional_ circumstances, for example, but should offer a side-channel return, without (expensive) throwing, for non-exceptional conditions, e.g. invalid user input. This is how .NET’s `TryParse` methods work, for example. Java’s… intransigence (for want of a better word) is what surprises me.

Comment: @Dai User's input has to be validated without parsing it blindly. Newer trust users) Cost for runtime exceptions doesn't matter, if it is not handled (which is normally the case), it crashes the app.

Comment: @Dai The successful case is cheap in any case but if you are concerned with the performance of the malformed input, you could simply check the string length, to skip when there are more than 20 characters, to rule out a large number of cases. But even when an exception occurs, it doesn’t have to be expensive. In a case like in this answer, chances are high that `parseLong` gets inlined into `safeParse` and since the exception is caught right in the same code then and provenly never tries to access the stack trace, even the exceptional case may get optimized to a simple `goto`.

Comment: @Holger "since the exception is caught right in the same code then and provenly never tries to access the stack trace, even the exceptional case may get optimized to a simple goto" - interesting! I wanted to find out more about this but I couldn't find any papers or specs that say the JVM (either HotSpot or GraalVM) actually optimize `throw` to a `goto` - do you have a link?

Comment: @Dai [The Exceptional Performance of Lil' Exception](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/)